# Tkinter の Toplevel() で、サブウィンドウを親としたサブウィンドウは作成可能か

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinterの `Toplevel()` ではメインウィンドウを親としたサブウィンドウを作成できますが、サブウィンドウを親としたサブウィンドウを作成することはできないのでしょうか？何か方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: どんな風に見えて欲しいとか、それらのウィンドウは何のためのものか、ウィンドウ間の連携や情報のやり取りはあるのか、といった詳細を追記すると助言や回答が得られ易くなるし、情報やノウハウの共有に役立つと思われます。実はこんなウィンドウを複数作りたいとかではありませんか？[\[Python\] Tkinterで複数のWindowを表示](https://qiita.com/kotai2003/items/0d6bafb753bb0374033c), [Tkinter Toplevel](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-toplevel/) あとはウィンドウ間の通信とか。[How to create child window and communicate with parent in TkInter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10718073/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

`Toplevel`には親ウィンドウを指定する`master`引数があります。
これを使用することでサブウィンドウを親としたサブウィンドウを作成することができます。

**サンプルコード**

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk

w1 = Tk()
w1.geometry("240x64+100+100")
ttk.Label(w1, text="親を閉じると子も孫も閉じます").grid(row=0, column=0)

# 親ウィンドウに w1 を指定
w2 = Toplevel(master=w1)
w2.geometry("240x64+100+200")
ttk.Label(w2, text="子を閉じると孫が閉じます").grid(row=0, column=0)

# 親ウィンドウに w2 を指定
w3 = Toplevel(master=w2)
w3.geometry("240x64+100+300")
ttk.Label(w3, text="孫を閉じるとは孫が閉じるということです").grid(row=0, column=0)

w1.mainloop()
```

(コメントを受けて追記)

下記のコードを使うと子ウィンドウのボタンで孫ウィンドウを呼び出すことができます。

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial

w1 = Tk()
w1.geometry("240x64+100+100")
ttk.Label(w1, text="親を閉じると子も孫も閉じます").grid(row=0, column=0)

# ボタンを押すと子が増える関数
def call_child(w_master: Misc):
    # 親ウィンドウに w2 を指定
    w_child = Toplevel(master=w_master)
    w_child.geometry("240x64")
    ttk.Button(w_child, text="Call child.", command=partial(call_child, w_child)).grid(row=0, column=0)

# 親ウィンドウに w1 を指定
w2 = Toplevel(master=w1)
w2.geometry("240x64+100+200")
ttk.Label(w2, text="子を閉じると孫が閉じます").grid(row=0, column=0)
ttk.Button(w2, text="Call child.", command=partial(call_child, w2)).grid(row=1, column=0)

# 親ウィンドウに w2 を指定
w3 = Toplevel(master=w2)
w3.geometry("240x64+100+300")
ttk.Label(w3, text="孫を閉じるとは孫が閉じるということです").grid(row=0, column=0)

w1.mainloop()
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。どういうわけか子ウィンドウのボタンで孫ウィンドウを呼び出すことができないのですが、原因がわかりますでしょうか。

Comment: 私の読解力が足りず、どういうわけか推測することができませんでした。手元の環境では子ウィンドウのボタンで孫ウィンドウを呼び出す(増やす)コードが意図通りに動作しましたので参考になれば幸いです。追記の内容がコメントの意図と異なる場合は、**コードを記載**した新しい質問をご作成していただくことで的確な回答を得やすくなります。

Comment: まさに意図に即したご回答をありがとうございます。他のプロジェクトと並行していますので、動作を確認次第またご報告させていただきます。丁寧にありがとうございます。